# Wireless problem with Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, debian-squeeze

I just have installed debian squeeze beta2 x64 on my laptop but it doesn't recognize my wireless card Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945 ABG. Is there generic drivers for wireless cards for Debian ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to install the [firmware-iwlwifi](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-iwlwifi) package, which provides non-free firmware. You might need to modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use `non-free` packages as well before `apt-get` or `aptitude` will find it.

[This](http://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi) is the page on the Debian Wiki that refers to your card.